# Android AppWidget - Not getting a result back from an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, widget

I've created an Android Widget.
I have a problem of getting a result from an activity back to it's AppWidgetProvider parent.
I looked for an answer over the web, did exactly what written in all the sites and it's not working.

I put a break point in onReceive method and it doesn't even enter there.

If someone can help me i will be very glad.
Attached is my code for the AppWidgetProvider and the activity named ContactsActivity.
Attached also in the manifest file.

**AppWidgetProvider:**

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i=0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

            Intent informationButtonIntent = new Intent(context, InfoActivity.class);
            informationButtonIntent.setAction(INFO_BUTTON_PRESSED);
            PendingIntent infoPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, informationButtonIntent, 0);

            Intent contactButtonIntent = new Intent(context, ContactsActivity.class);
            contactButtonIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            contactButtonIntent.setAction(CONTACT_BUTTON_PRESSED);
            PendingIntent contactPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, contactButtonIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Intent freeNumberButtonIntent = new Intent(context, FreeSMSNumberActivity.class);
            contactButtonIntent.setAction(FREE_NUMBER_BUTTON_PRESSED);
            PendingIntent freeNumberPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, freeNumberButtonIntent, 0);

            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.informationButton, infoPendingIntent);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.contactsButton, contactPendingIntent);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.freeTextButton, freeNumberPendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // v1.5 fix that doesn't call onDelete Action
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
            final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
                this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
            }
        }

        else if (intent.getAction().equals("CONTACT_BUTTON_PRESSED")) {

        }


        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

**ContactsActivity:**

```
public class ContactsActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 3;

    int mAppWidgetId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        Log.d(UndisclosedSMS.TAG_LOGGER, "Contacts button was pressed");

        Intent parentIntent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = parentIntent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(reqCode){
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            }
            else {
                Intent resultValue = new Intent();
                resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, resultValue);
                finish();
            }
            finish();
        }
    }
    finish();
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.LogiaGroup.UndisclosedSMS"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <receiver android:name=".UndisclosedSMS" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/undisclose_sms_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".InfoActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.LogiaGroup.UndisclosedSMS.INFO_BUTTON_PRESSED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ContactsActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.LogiaGroup.UndisclosedSMS.CONTACT_BUTTON_PRESSED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".FreeSMSNumberActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.LogiaGroup.UndisclosedSMS.FREE_NUMBER_BUTTON_PRESSED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

</manifest>
```

Thank you very much!